# How to approve/mark docker image for testing, staging & productions

Tags: docker, artifactory, devops

I am developing a tool at workspace to do AWS activities like bring up EC2 nodes and with given docker image.

Now we want to develop a feature like - tag a specific docker image for testing ready, then staging ready then production ready. Basically we want to restrict production deploy with approved docker images.

I am new to dev-ops/cloud area and we are using jFrog artifactory.

Can someone suggest me how to deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply various tags to a docker image.  E.g., if I start with a docker image from docker hub:

```
docker pull fedora:26
```

Where `fedora` is the "repository" and `26` is the tag.  I can apply additional tags to this image, for example:

```
docker tag fedora:26 fedora:dev
```

Now the image `fedora:dev` points to the same image.  Similarly, I could:

```
docker tag fedora:26 fedora:prod
```

Comment: But I want to tag them programmatically. Through the UI, tester/developer wants to approve a build and only approved builds should be deployed to prod.

Answer (score 0):

JFrog Artifactory allows you to manage multiple Docker registries on one Artifactory instance.
This means you can create a separate registry for dev/test/staging/prod and [promote](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-PromotingDockerImages) images between the registries.
Since Artifactory is using a checksum based storage, the image layers will be stored only once so you will not consume more disk space when promoting images between registries.
You can read more about this in this blog post: [Taking Docker to Production with Confidence](https://www.jfrog.com/blog/docker-registry-to-production/)